# In Django, can I exclude a field in ModelForm sub-subclass?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, modelform, django-1.3

I have a “generic” `InternForm` that inherits from `ModelForm` and defines common messages, widgets, etc.

I defined a subclass called `ApplyInternForm` for application form that is accessible to everyone and I want to hide some of the “advanced” fields.

**How can I override `exclude` setting in the form's subclass?**

```
class InternForm(ModelForm):

    # ...

    class Meta:
        model = Intern
        exclude = ()

class ApplyInternForm(InternForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ApplyInternForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.Meta.exclude = ('is_active',)  # this doesn't work
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `self._meta`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Defining a `Meta` class in the subclass worked for me:

```
class InternForm(ModelForm):

    # ...

    class Meta:
        model = Intern

class ApplyInternForm(InternForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Intern
        exclude = ('is_active',)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not in this way, no. When you subclass a form the fields you want to exclude are already there. You can however remove them from `self.fields` after calling `super()` in your `__init__()`.

Comment: The only one solution I found

Answer (score -1):

You can change widget to hidden:

```
class ApplyInternForm(InternForm):
    class Meta:
        widgets = {
            'is_active': forms.HiddenInput(required=False),
        }
```